# How to keep table footer together with details? Reportig Services (RDLC)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm using **Tablix** control to display data. Have also **tablix footer** for some summaries.
Works well except one scenario: when last tablix row is printed as last on page then (summary) **footer is moved to another page**.

So it looks like

> row-1
> row-2
> ....
> row-20
> **<< end-of-page >>**
> summary_row (footer)

This looks pretty bad what I would like to archive is:

> row-1
> row-2
> ....
> **<< end-of-page >>**
> row-19
> row-20
>
> summary_row (footer)

Basically would like to have (at least) one row together with summary on next page.

Any idea how to archive that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each row will take up the same amount of space on the page, you can calculate how many rows will fit on a page (including the summary), and then put the tablix into a list object set to page break on group with a group expression similar to:

=Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/25)
(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(v=sql.90).aspx)