# SSRS: How to keep a table footer together with last detail of last group?

Tags: reporting, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a problem that is related to [one which has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649550/how-to-keep-table-footer-together-with-details-reportig-services-rdlc), but slightly more complex, so unfortunately, the supplied answer doesn't help me.

I'm using a Tablix control (`Table1`) to display data. My data consists of 1..n items (`Table1_Group1`) having 1..n detail items (`Table1_Details_Group`), so a typical report will have a structure like this:

> row-0
>   . row-0-detail-1
>   row-1
>   . row-1-detail-1
>   . row-1-detail-2
>   . row-1-detail-3
>   . row-1-detail-4
>   . row-1-detail-5
>   . row-1-detail-6
>   footer

Note that those detail rows can easily span multiple pages!

The table footer is a kludgy handmade variety which works as follows: it is present on every row item (extra row behind the details group) but only visible if the item the last one of the table. The visibility expression for that row is `=(Fields!TestCode.Value <> Last(Fields!TestCode.Value, "Table1"))`.

This works very well except for one scenario: **if the last row's details happen to exactly fill the page, the footer is moved to the next page.** So I end up with another page that just contains the footer:

> row-0
>   . row-0-detail-1
>   row-1
>   . row-1-detail-1
>   . row-1-detail-2
>   . row-1-detail-3
>   . row-1-detail-4
>   . row-1-detail-5
>   . row-1-detail-6
>   **<< end-of-page >>**
>   footer

What I'm looking for is a forced page break before the last detail, such as this:

> row-0
>   . row-0-detail-1
>   row-1
>   . row-1-detail-1
>   . row-1-detail-2
>   . row-1-detail-3
>   . row-1-detail-4
>   . row-1-detail-5
>   **<< end-of-page >>**
>   . row-1-detail-6
>   footer

I have already tried creating the footer inside my `Table1_Details_Group`, but didn't get it to work. I didn't manage to get access to the status of the containing item to see if it's the last one of the table.

I'd be happy to get any hints or suggestions how I could achieve this. Also, please don't hesitate to suggest different footer mechanisms if they work better.

Answer (score 0):

using the group property "KeepTogether" should help you solving this